# asp.net automatically download image on click on the image

Tags: c#, asp.net

i am new to asp.net and would like to know or a sample of code on how to automatically download image on click on the image. My images are dynamically generated. This is the code where my images generated from code behind.

```
foreach (HtmlNode n in nodes)
    {
        string img = n.InnerHtml;
        if (n.InnerHtml.Contains(" ")) { img = n.InnerHtml.Replace(" ", "%20"); }
        count++; 
        if (count == 1) {
            newhtml = "<img src =http://img.crwd.io/" + img+" width=\"320px\">";
            table.Rows.Add(new TableRow());
            table.Rows[row].Cells.Add(new TableCell());
            table.Rows[row].Cells.Add(new TableCell());
            table.Rows[row].Cells.Add(new TableCell());
            table.Rows[row].Cells.Add(new TableCell());
            table.Rows[row].Cells[0].Text = newhtml;
        }
        else if (count == 4) {
            newhtml = "<img src =http://img.crwd.io/" + img + " width=\"320px\">";
            table.Rows[row].Cells[3].Text = newhtml; 
            count = 0; 
            row++; }
        else if (count == 3) { 
            newhtml = "<img src =http://img.crwd.io/" + img + " width=\"320px\">"; 
            table.Rows[row].Cells[2].Text = newhtml; }
        else if (count == 2) { 
            newhtml = "<img src =http://img.crwd.io/" + img + " width=\"320px\">"; 
            table.Rows[row].Cells[1].Text = newhtml; }
    }
```

and i wanted when image is clicked it will automatically downloaded from user if possible to a specific location. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just make them a link:

```
var url = string.Format("http://img.crwd.io/{0}", img);
newhtml = string.Format("<a href=\"{0}\" target=\"_blank\">" +
    "<img src=\"{0}\" width=\"320px\"></a>", url);
```

If you do it this way, the browser will handle everything for you.

---

**UPDATE:** based on the comments below, an ActiveX control needs to be created.

Comment: Hey mate, what i mean is that when user clicks on any of the images, it will automatically be downloaded. Just automatic nothing else..thanks :)

Comment: @Wylan, that's not possible without an ActiveX control, and that only works in IE. Further, it's quite frankly not safe. The browsers job is to protect the user from exactly what you're explaining.

Comment: Its actually okay because it is password protected. It is not actually visible or accessible to any users, only the team (we).

Comment: @WylanOsorio, then you'll need to build an ActiveX control; and that only works in IE. The ActiveX control, when loaded, will request access to the machine and then you have direct access to anything C# can run.